# jasmine expect not matching array result

Tags: javascript, arrays, jasmine, expectations

I'm trying the following code:

```
describe("array deletion", function () {
    it("leaves a hole in middle", function () {
        var array = ['one','two','three'];
        delete array[1]; //'two' deleted
        expect(array).toEqual(['one',undefined,'three']);
    });
});
```

This expectation fails, but why? shouldn't it equal?

Comment: How does the expectation fail?

Comment: The expectation doesn't fail when run at http://tryjasmine.com/ - could you provide more environment information (node/browser, versions etc)?

Comment: I'm running the tests under Karma v0.13.9, browser Chrome 46.0.2490 (Windows 7 0.0.0). Node v0.12.7

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in JavaScript between array that has 3 elements one of them is `undefined` and array that has only 2 elements. For example

```
var a = [1,2,3];
delete a[1];
a.forEach(function(x) { console.log(x); });
// writes 1 3

[1,undefined,3].forEach(function(x) { console.log(x); })
// writes 1 undefined 3
```

also

```
1 in a
// returns false

1 in [1,undefined,2]
// returns true
```

Source is always on your side, if you look at `toEquals` matcher code you will find that it uses `eq` function from following source file (it is a bit lengthy so I provide only link, at the bottom is the part that compares objects and arrays: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/79206ccff5dd8a8b2970ccf5a6429cdab2c6010a/src/core/matchers/matchersUtil.js).